# Alfresco: Backup and Restore Issue

Tags: alfresco

I followed Backup and restore method in alfresco share instead of import/export. It is now working as i expected in new Alfresco, i can see the content in sites, can view files in site document library, can view events, workflow,users,groups and so on. Everything goes fine except that the repository is not loading, but When i search for files in repository it is showing "3 result(s) found in Quality site."...but it is not displaying those files.

In my old Alfresco i have set permissions for folders in repository...will it cause any error to load repository in my new alfresco?

It shows following error when i close my server...

log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.

Kindly look into my issue and give some suggestion......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error means that the log4j tries to log something in the log file of the webapp but Tomcat already shut down. have you sufficient/right permissions on the new restored alfresco installation?
If you followed correctly the backup/restore procedure from the wiki, the permissions on nodes of the repository also come together. But, if you want to reset and rebuild all the permission, you could perform a FULL reindex with the string appended to alfresco.global.properties:

```
index.recovery.mode=FULL
```